# How is it possible to have selectors in a textfield eg. to categorize search inputs

Tags: material-ui

This question evolved over time.
The objective is: having a nice guided selection / searchbar.

Initially I thought the approach would be to add other components into a mui textfield. Meanwhile I learned about [mui autocomplete example: githubs-picker](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#githubs-picker) which gets pretty close to what I'm looking for.

I'd like to have something similar like the gitlab searchbar in my mui project.

Thanks for information, howto, libs!

[image: gitlab search bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I solved it with start adornments which get dynamically populated based on a population function; I'm not overly happy with that, as it doesn't work nicely, especially in multilines. If there's another suggestion, please let me know.

The population function is triggered by changes on the textfield.
This population function selects valid entries and thereby controls/updates the source for the content of the adornment.

```js
<TextField
  onChange={(event)=>console.log('Text in Textfield is: ', event.target.value)}
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={(e)=>console.log('loading it now',e)}>
        load something
      </Button>
      <Select onChange={()=>console.log('changed')}>
      {optionsA.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
          {option}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
      </Select>
      <div>value:</div>
      </>
    ),
  }}
/>
```